# New NetQosPolicy

Tags: powershell, voip, qos, windows-phone-voip

I am attempting to set up a new quality of service for VoIP on windows 8.1.  As I do not have Pro the "gpedit.msc" is unavailable so I am utilizing Windows Power Shell to create a Quality of Service Policy with the New-NetQosPolicy parameter.  Unfortunately the traffic is still populating as the default O through WireShark.  I have tried disabling the entire firewall and simply allowing the softphone through all 3 levels of the firewall to no avail.  My policies are below, while they are both successfully set they are not working.

NOTE: This is a physical machine, not virtual.

```
New-NetQosPolicy -Name "Line of Business VOICE" -AppPathNameMatchCondition "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\VoIPphone.exe" -DSCPAction 46 -IPProtocolMatchCondition UDP -IPSrcPortEndMatchCondition 20000 -IPSrcPortStartMatchCondition 10000 -PolicyStore "MY-PC" -UserMatchCondition "Me"

New-NetQosPolicy -Name "Line of Business SIP" -AppPathNameMatchCondition "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\VoIPphone.exe" -DSCPAction 24 -IPProtocolMatchCondition UDP -IPSrcPortMatchCondition 5060 -PolicyStore "MY-PC" -UserMatchCondition "Me"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change out the %ProgramFiles(x86)% for ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}?

Comment: Same DSCP results, default 0x00.